# Service worker update period

Tags: service-worker, browser-cache

I'm creating a simple web app that can connect to a bluetooth device that I want to be able to use offline, so I use a service worker to store the app in the web cache. I know the cache only clears if there is no more space but what about the service worker?

I found that is lifespan is 24 hours. My question is how long can I use the web app without connecting to the internet? Is the cache the only problem or does the service worker "die" after x amount of time and I need to connect to the internet again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not die. You can use it forever.

You're confusing two things. The 24 hour lifespan is actually an automatic update checking interval. In other words, when using a site frequently the browser will automatically check for updated Service Workers (specifically updated /serviceworker.js or wherever you store it). Your code can of course manually, programmatically check for SW updates more often. Usually apps check for new SWs every time they're launched. But the device may be offline for eg a month and that doesn't prevent the use of the app.

Comment: > _You can use it forever._ < -- I noticed when inspecting "security settings" of an offline PWA that it [keeps the certificate information](https://discourse.mozilla.org/t/getsecurityinfo-for-pwas/81239/1#:~:text=provides%20the,served%20offline%20by%20a%20Service%20Worker) around. Certs from Let's Encrypt (the only *gratis* TLS issuer respected by Mozilla, Google, or Microsoft these days) expire 90 days after issuance. Has anyone actually run a PWA/SW on an offline device for such an amount of time to see what happens? Does it just evict the SW? Can I keep clicking through to the ToFU'd cert?